# rmagick and imagemagick bundle/homebrew error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, bundler, homebrew, rmagick

Please see error stack below. I tried uninstall/install of imagemagick via homebrew, 'gem pristine rmagick', and reinstall of rmagick. All have returned the same error. Any help would be VERY much appreciated- been at this for a while now.

```
$ gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/LU/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
extconf.rb:128: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick++... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/Lungs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby
    --with-MagickCorelib
    --without-MagickCorelib
    --with-Magicklib
    --without-Magicklib
    --with-Magick++lib
    --without-Magick++lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Lungs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/LU/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

Comment: could be it needs some dev packacke of imagemagick, should be named something like libmagick-dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being an issue with rails version, needed to update and reinstall imagemagick/rmagick.

Answer (score 12):

Had the same problem, easy fix!

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16625

here is the skinny on the solution (rmagick is broken, and you have to create symlinks to get it to work):

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/lib

ln -s libMagick++-Q8.7.dylib   libMagick++.dylib

ln -s libMagickCore-Q8.7.dylib libMagickCore.dylib

ln -s libMagickWand-Q8.7.dylib libMagickWand.dylib
```

Comment: In my installation of ImageMagick, the file names were slightly different. Instead of `libMagick++-Q8.7.dylib` I had `libMagick++-Q16.7.dylib`. So I created the symlinks to those files instead. It worked! Thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I had to do the same as I also had `Q16.7` but `bundle install` then worked a treat.

Comment: Thanks! same here - been trying to resolve this for hours. with the q16 modification this worked. if you run the Q8 lines first by mistake, simply brew uninstall then install again, then run the Q16 lines.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, step back one ImageMagick rev:

(via https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832084/485836)

```
> cd /usr/local

> brew versions imagemagick

6.7.7-6  git checkout 883f549 Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
6.7.5-7  git checkout f965101 Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
6.7.1-1  git checkout be8e0ff Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
...

> git checkout 883f549 Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb

> brew install imagemagick
```

Answer (score 2):

A better way to get the headers into the proper place might be to just add the pkgconfig from the imagemagick Cellar to your PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

Adding the following to my ~/.bash_profile and then sourcing it (`source ~/.bash_profile`) worked for me

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

Answer (score -3):

```
brew install imagemagick
```

should do the trick. Then reinstall the gems.